# Фильтрация таблицы по дате

Tags: javascript, html

В таблицу с помощью Java генерируем записи из БД.
Каким образом реализовать фильтрацию записей по дате, например в определенном диапазоне.
Что бы при вводе даты ***от*** и ***до*** показывались необходимые записи.

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Сотрудник</th>
        <th>Руководитель</th>
        <th>Тип</th>
        <th>Сумма</th>
        <th>Коментарий</th>
        <th>Дата</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Шуткин</td>
        <td>Фоменко</td>
        <td>С</td>
        <td>12300</td>
        <td>потому что</td>
        <td>03.06.2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Бременко</td>
        <td>Агутин</td>
        <td>Т</td>
        <td>20000</td>
        <td>прост</td>
        <td>06.07.2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Володин</td>
        <td>Жирков</td>
        <td>О</td>
        <td>45000</td>
        <td>пампам</td>
        <td>21.04.2020</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашел такое вот решение данного вопроса.

```
$(function() {
  //name part
  $("#name").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#my-table").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find('td').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });


  $("#from,#to").bind('keyup change', function() {

    var val1 = moment($('#from').val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    var val2 = moment($('#to').val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');

    $("#my-table").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle((moment($(this).find('td').text().toLowerCase(),
        'YYYY/MM/DD') >= (val1) || !val1["_isValid"]) && (moment($(this).find('td').text()
        .toLowerCase(),
        'YYYY/MM/DD') <= (val2) || !val2["_isValid"]))
    });
    //console.log(val1["_isValid"], val2["_isValid"]);
  })


});
```

Обращайте внимание на формат даты.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .container input {
      width: 25%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .list-group {
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .list-group td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 5px 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    Date from : <input class="form-control" id="from" type="date"> to : <input class="form-control" id="to" type="date">
    <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Search by name...">
    <br>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="my-table">
        <tr class="list-group">
          <td>2019-07-08</td>
          <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
          <td>2015-01-30</td>
          <td>notif</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
          <td>2016-03-10</td>
          <td>food</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
          <td>2014-09-10</td>
          <td>yop</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="list-group">
          <td>2017-12-30</td>
          <td>wick</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```